# Zxing QR code scanner is turning off flush light automatically

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, android-camera2

I have integrated Zxing QR scanner library. This is my app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
}
```

In `onCreate()` method I have

```
mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        cameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList();
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.d("camera", "error");
    }
    setFlushLight(cameraId[0], true);
```

So flush light is turned ON when app starts.Then I press my "Start QR scanner" button which starts QR scanner and I get the parsed result as expected.

This is the code used to parse qr code:

```
private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

//Getting the scan results
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String latestScannedData;

    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            //if qrcode has nothing in it
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //if qr contains data
            latestScannedData = result.getContents();
            latestScannedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (latestScannedData.equals(previousData)) {
                //if this data equals previous data
                //tell to remove the card
                if (latestScannedTime - previousScanTime > n * 1000) {
                    //if last scan was more than n seconds ago
                    t1.speak("Please remove the card", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    previousData = "";
                }
                qrScan.initiateScan();
            } else {
                t1.speak("Access granted", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                qrScan.initiateScan();
                previousData = latestScannedData;
                previousScanTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            Log.d("qrresult", result.getContents());
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**My Problem is :**

The ZXing QR scanner **automatically turns OFF** the flush light ( where my requirement is to scan in a dark environment, so light is mandatory)

I also post a portion of my Log:

```
D/CameraPreview: resume()
D/CameraInstance: Opening camera
D/CameraInstance: Configuring camera
I/CameraManager: Camera Display Orientation: 90

I/CameraConfiguration: Requesting focus mode value from among: [auto]
I/CameraConfiguration: Supported focus mode values: [auto, infinity, fixed, macro, continuous-video, continuous-picture, manual]
I/CameraConfiguration: Can set focus mode to: auto
I/CameraConfiguration: Focus mode already set to auto
I/CameraConfiguration: Requesting flash mode value from among: [off]
I/CameraConfiguration: Supported flash mode values: [off, auto, on, torch]
I/CameraConfiguration: Can set flash mode to: off
I/CameraConfiguration: Flash mode already set to off
I/PreviewScalingStrategy: Viewfinder size: 1920x1080
I/CameraPreview: Starting preview
D/CameraInstance: Starting preview
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x55a98da7b0 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x55a9894a00
I/AutoFocusManager: Current focus mode 'auto'; use auto focus? true
```

**How can I keep flush light turned on ?**

Comment: I just added the mentioned code in app/build.gradle, and  clicking 'sync now' was enough

Comment: Yes I used IntentIntegrator, I edited my answer, how I did that ?

Comment: Please update on how you resolved.  I've got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `IntentIntegrator` contains a configuration for the torch. But this part of the code is not yet released, so you'd have to use a snapshot build from `master`. It also appears that the `CameraManager` switches off the torch light when configuring the camera on all released versions.

### Unreleased approach

Before initiating the scan, just call

```
qrScan.setTorchEnabled(true);
```

You can even handle the torch with the volume keys, where up is *ON*.

Just be aware that the torch might be switched off after any scan, so maybe don't handle it with `setFlushLight(cameraId[0], true)` and only make sure a scan starts with the torch flag.

Comment: Error shows: Cannot resolve method qrScan.setTorchEnabled(boolean);

Comment: Right, this part seems to be unreleased. Even though it was implemented a year ago. You could try to use the `master` snapshot with _JitPack_.

Comment: Do you mean something like this ? : https://jitpack.io/p/leafclick/barcodescanner

Comment: But it also seems that builds failed there, so maybe using an alternative or a working fork would be advisable.

Comment: As a beginner in android, I ask where to add : dependencies {
        implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
 }  ----- in app/build.grade or root build.gradle?

Comment: It's a runtime dependency. Therefore in app/build.gradle.